# How do I re-install Ubuntu without losing data?

Tags: installation, backup, re-installation

I dont know how to reinstall Ubuntu, set up my partitions, or save my data (pictures, videos and documents). What should I do first? My system was set up by someone I no longer speak with.

Comment: The secret to getting a good answer is to ask a good question.  The secret to asking a good question is to understand your problem, break it down if you can into steps, and then asking questions about the steps you can't do.  If you can't do that, the secret to understanding your problem is to explain what symptoms you are having, and asking for help or advice on how to go about solving the problem.  Are you sure you want to reinstall?  Do you have another OS on the disk, like Windows?  Why do you need to "fix" your partitions - are they broken?

Comment: Hi Justin, It would help us if we knew more about your situation. Does your computer only boot Ubuntu, or do you have the ability to choose between Ubuntu and MS Windows (or another OS) at boot-up? Also, could you run the command 'df -h' in a terminal window and paste the result here so we can see how your partitions are currently set up please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a dual boot and wan to re-partition, you will want to back up all the files you want to save on a type of storage medium (e.g. USB or CD) After you have backed up your files, to edit your partitions, download GParted partition editor in Ubuntu software center and use it to edit your partitions. Just to be safe, make sure you have the disks for reinstalling the other OS on the computer. If you want to begin anew and make your computer entirely Ubuntu, just boot from the USB or CD with Ubuntu on it and install, this time not next to the other OS(s). Remember to back up all wanted files before taking any action.